# How do call a javascript file from another Rails project? ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/trackmetrics.js")

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api

I am currently testing out my API which has a JS script in the assets folder -- trackmetrics.js. I created another rails app for testing purposes, and I am trying to call trackmetrics.js file from another url localhost:3003

Trackmetrics app is on localhost:3000 while
Simple app is on localhost:3003

My Simple app has the following code in the view:

```
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//localhost:3000/assets/trackmetrics.js" %>
<script>
    Trackmetrics.setAuthToken('######################################');
    Trackmetrics.send(“page_view”,{test: true});
</script>
```

Is there a way for Simple App to GET the trackmetrics.js file that's in Trackmetrics on localhost:3000? I have both applications running and I ran into the following error when testing it:

```
Started GET "/assets/trackmetrics.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 21:59:38 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/trackmetrics.js"):
```

My Trackmetrics.js file looks like this:

```
var Trackmetrics = {
  authToken: null,
  setAuthToken: function(auth_token) {
    this.authToken = auth_token;
  },
  send: function(name, data) {
    var _bm_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    _bm_request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/events.json", true);
    _bm_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    _bm_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // this function runs when the Ajax request changes state.
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
    };
    _bm_request.send(JSON.stringify({auth_token: this.authToken, name: name, data: data}));
  }
}
```

Also, I have tried setting my `config.serve_static_assets = false` and did

```
rake assets:precompile...and I am still running into the error.
```

Comment: On which app did the error come from?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot The error is showing up on my Trackmetrics localhost:3000 console, since I am trying to call it from Simple App with those script tags in Simple App's view

Comment: That's weird. Does `localhost:3000/assets/trackmetrics.js` work if you paste in a browser address bar?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Hmm no it doesn't...that's odd...I have the file in the assets folder. No route matches [GET] "/assets/trackmetrics.js"

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I just pasted my trackmetrics.js file code.

Comment: What if you go to your app on 3000 and look at the source and click on the javascript file and see if it loads in your browser. then copy the URL and use that.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Hmm it doesn't work..both applications work fine..it's just that <%= javascript_include_tag "//localhost:3000/assets/trackmetrics.js" %> doesn't seem to be loading..can I even load a js file through the javascript_include_tag?

Comment: When I look at the public/assets folder of my application, I see all the assets fingerprinted, ie. image-aabbccblahblah.png. In addition, all my javascript is compiled in application-aabbccddeeff.js. What do you see in your public/assets folder?

Comment: @JohnJudd Gosh...thank you for pointing it out...I had my trackmetrics.js file in the wrong assets folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue of one app calling another apps javascript. It looks like the app on :3000 doesn't recognize the route. Get it working on the first app first!

Comment: yeah, I managed to get it working. Apparently, I had the file in the wrong assets folder.